Does Digital Ocean spaces api token has granular permissions?
I was trying to create an API key for programmatically access DO space objects. When I try to create an API key, it looks like the key will get full permission to do any operations on all the spaces. When I checked the documentation, I saw this:

Users who connect with access keys can create, destroy, read, and
write to all of the buckets for the account.

So, is there a way to create an API key and give granular access permission to those key. Example, I need to create a key and need to set only read permission to that key for a specific bucket.

Looks like an issue for DO's support
